# Showing the first/last constant from a SwiftUI Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swiftui, set

I'm wondering if it's possible to pick the first and last `Bool = true` from `car` to place them in a `Text`? If so, I'd probably need to rewrite the `let month` to another thing like "march" to "March".

```
struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let january: Bool, let february: Bool, let march: Bool // etc to december
}

let cars = [
    Car(name: "Peugeot 208", january: false, february: false, march: false, april: false, may: true, june: true, july: true, august: true, september: false, october: false, november: false, december: false),
    Car(name: "Dacia Sandero", january: false, february: false, march: true, april: true, may: false, june: false, july: false, august: false, september: false, october: false, november: false, december: false)
]

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(cars.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) { car in
            Text(car.name)
            Text("From \(?) to \(?)") // if Peugeot 208: From May to August
        }
    }
}
```

Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: You are probably better off turning all those variables into an enum or Int, or even a protocol. Going from a Bool value to a variable name is possible but overly involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You data has no sense of sequence to the month booleans. which is why you are struggling to get the output you want.  You need to give it some.  One option is via an enum.  If you conform the enum to `Comparable` you get automatic inference of sequence by the order of the elements

```
enum Months: Comparable {
   case Jan
   case Feb 
   case Mar
   // etc
}
```

which then lets you record the months in a more intuitive way (I'm assuming this is about ownership, but rename the properties as appropriate!)

```
struct Car {
   let name: String
   let owned: Set<Months>
}
```

which in turn will allow you to calculate the start and end months.

```
extension Car {
   var ownership: String {
      guard !owned.isEmpty else {return "Not owned"}
      let range = owned.sorted(by: <)
      return "\(range.first!) to \(range.last!)"
   }
   
}
```

In use

```
let car1 = Car(name: "Ford", owned: [.Feb, .Mar, .Jan])
let car2 = Car(name: "Volvo", owned: [.Mar, .Feb])

print(car1.ownership) //"Jan to Mar"
print(car2.ownership) //"Feb to Mar"
```

You can then use the `ownership` property in your SwiftUI Text view.

**EDIT**
The OP asks the reasonable question how this would handle date ranges that cross year boundaries.  This is mainly an issue for the input to the problem space.  Once the date is there, it's relatively easy to extend the solution.  Here's one possible way of doing it:

```
enum Months: Comparable {
   case Jan
   case Feb 
   case Mar
   case July
   //... 
   case Dec
}

struct Period: Comparable, Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
   var description: String { "\(month) \(year)" }
   
   static func < (lhs: Period, rhs: Period) -> Bool {
      lhs.year == rhs.year ? lhs.month < rhs.month : lhs.year < rhs.year
   }
   
   let month: Months
   let year: Int
}

struct Car {
   let name: String
   let owned: Set<Period>
}

extension Car {
   var ownership: String {
      guard !owned.isEmpty else {return "Not owned"}
      let range = owned.sorted(by: <)
      return "\(range.first!) to \(range.last!)"
   }
   
}

let car5 = Car(name: "Ford", owned: [.init(month: .Jan, year: 2023), .init(month: .Dec, year: 2023)])
let car6 = Car(name: "Volvo", owned: [.init(month: .Jan, year: 2023), .init(month: .Dec, year: 2022)])


print(car5.ownership)  //Jan 2023 to Dec 2023
print(car6.ownership)  //Dec 2022 to Jan 2023
```

Comment: And if you have `[.feb, .july]`, does it return the expected value (it's also a question for the author)? Also, I'd recommend to name `jan` instead of `Jan`.

Comment: @Larme not sure I get your point about `[.feb, .july]'?  They won't work as they are not instances of the enum.  [I do take your point that enum instances are typically lowercased, but when they represent proper nouns I'm happy with either style].

Comment: That was also more a question for the author: Can you have "gaps" between values: "[.feb, .july]" means from february to july, or february and july months only (not the one between them), can you also have more than 2 values, etc.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I'll leave the business rules to the OP. Although it would be quite easy to handle this in the computed property if they need a hint :)

Comment: @Larme It's pretty straightforward if you look at the `extension` so yes you can have a gap. It can also be empty, thanks to the returned String. I only have one problem: if I use `[.Dec, .Jan]` to get `Dec to Jan` I get the reverse. I don't know yet how to modify the `extension`. It will also be boring to translate in 4 languages. But thanks to @flanker as well.

Comment: @Alexnnd that's a fair point about things going over a year boundary, but the problem lies in your input - there's no way to tell if you mean, for example, Jan 23 -> Dec 23 or Dec 22 -> Jan 23.  If you can work out a way to express that in the problem space then the answer could also be expanded.

Comment: @flanker Actually, I would prefer to get "Dec to Jan" from `[.Dec, .Jan]` without the years. I have to figure out how to make `first` and `last` work without `.sorted(by: <)`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's just an output detail, doesn't affect the logic. Just change the `description` computer property to omit the year, i.e. `var description: String { "\(month) }`